# How to build iOS app for a few testers to download

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am submitting my app to a big app expo, but for their judges to judge it (since it can't be put on the app store) I need to distribute it on a website with an ad hoc build. However, wouldn't I need to manually add the UUD of each phone that is used to judge the app?

Comment: https://testflightapp.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out **[TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com)** - this is a free app testing service which allows you to show off and/or distribute your app to your testers without any difficulty.

Comment: As an annotation, you still need to add each testing device in the provisioning portal. But TestFlight also adds features such as aggregated crash reports, "checkpoints" and direct textual user feedback.

Comment: Test flight is great, you can once your testers are signed up download a file with all the UUIDs, upload that to apple and create the correct distribution certificate. Also you can add that certifacte after the fact, that means if you have a build uploaded to Testflight you can add a new certificate if you get new testers. YOu dont have to upload a new build